# Increase performance/speed

Tags: performance, r, loops, raster

I need to take data from 1303 rasters (each raster has data for 1 month) and make a time series for each grid cell in the rasters. In the end I will join all the time series into one massive (zoo) file.

I have the code that can do it (I tried on a small portion of the dataset and it worked) but it seems to be taking for ever just to stack the raster (more than 2 hours now and still counting) and this is not the slower part, that will be doing the time series. So here is my code, if anyone knows a faster way to stack rasters and /or to create the time series (maybe without the double loop?) please help...

I don't know any other programming language but would this be just too much to ask from R?

```
files <- list.files(pattern=".asc") 
pat <- "^.*pet_([0-9]{1,})_([0-9]{1,}).asc$"
ord_files <- as.Date(gsub(pat, sprintf("%s-%s-01", "\\1", "\\2"), files))
files<-files[order(ord_files)]


#using "raster" package to import data 
s<- raster(files[1])
pet<-vector()
for (i in 2:length(files))
{
r<- raster(files[i])
s <- stack(s, r)
}

#creating a data vector
beginning = as.Date("1901-01-01")
full <- seq(beginning, by='1 month', length=length(files))
dat<-as.yearmon(full)

#building the time series
for (lat in 1:360)
for (long in 1:720)
{
pet<-as.vector(s[lat,long])
x <- xts(pet, dat)
write.zoo(x,file=paste("P:/WRSRL/Users1/ncgk/IBERIA/cru_pet/zoo/","lat",lat,"long",long,".csv", sep="")  , sep=",")
}
```

Comment: The question is, which part of the code takes how much time. The last double-loop will be executed  360*720 times, that's a lot. If you have more than one CPU you could run in in parallel (have a look at foreach).

Comment: I am still struggling with importing all the files, I thought the raster package would be the best option after reading a few posts here but I am not sure it works for 1303 files. But `read.table` is even worse!

Comment: Then the problem may be the following: For each iteration R needs to allocate a new object S with increasing size. This allocation can cost a lot of time. It could be faster to allocate s before the loop. I give you an trivial example:
your way:
`s = c()`;
`for(i in 1:10){ s <- c(s, rnorm(100)) } `
faster:
`s = rep(NA, 1000)`;
`for(i in seq(1,10*100,100)){ s[i:(i+99)] <- rnorm(100) }` (sorry, this looks ugly as a comment)

Answer (score 2):

The first bit could simply be:

```
s <- stack(files)
```

The reason why creating a stack is somewhat slow is that each file needs to be opened and checked to see if it has the same nrow, ncol etc. as the other files. If you are *absolutely certain* that is the case, you can use a shortcut like this (NOT generally recommended)

```
quickStack <- function(f) {
r <- raster(f[1])
ln <- extension(basename(f), '')
s <- stack(r)
s@layers <- sapply(1:length(f), function(x){ r@file@name = f[x]; r@layernames=ln[x]; r@data@haveminmax=FALSE ; r })
s@layernames <- ln
s
}

quickStack(files)
```

You can probably also speed up the second part as in the below examples, depending on how much RAM you have.

Read row by row:

```
for (lat in 1:360) {
pet <- getValues(s, lat, 1)
for (long in 1:720) {
    x <- xts(pet[long,], dat)
    write.zoo(x,file=paste("P:/WRSRL/Users1/ncgk/IBERIA/cru_pet/zoo/","lat",lat,"long",long,".csv", sep="")  , sep=",")
}
}
```

more extreme, read all values in one go:

```
 pet <- getValues(s)
 for (lat in 1:360) {
for (long in 1:720) {
    cell <- (lat-1) * 720 + long
    x <- xts(pet[cell,], dat)
    write.zoo(x,file=paste("P:/WRSRL/Users1/ncgk/IBERIA/cru_pet/zoo/","lat",lat,"long",long,".csv", sep="")  , sep=",")
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will repost my comment here and give a better example:

The general idea: allocate the space for s before the 'raster'-loop is executed. If you concatenate s and r to a new object s inside the loop, R has to allocate new memory for s for each iteration. This is really slow, especially if s is large.

```
s <- c()
system.time(for(i in 1:1000){ s <- c(s, rnorm(100))})
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.584   0.244   0.885 

s <- rep(NA, 1000*100)
system.time(for(i in seq(1,1000*100,100)){ s[i:(i+99)] <- rnorm(100) })
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.052   0.000   0.050
```

as you can see, pre-allocation is around 10 times faster.

Unfortunately I am not familiar with `raster`  and `stack` so I can not tell you how to apply this to your code.

Comment: thanks, I tried to do this by allocating the space before the loop:  `files1<-files[1:20]
arr<-array(data = NA, dim =   c(360,720,length(files1)))
for (i in 1:length(files1))
{dat<-read.table(files1[i], skip=6)}` but it took 8 sec for 20 files, while using the raster package it took 3 seconds. I never used raster and stack before so I don't now how to pre-alocate with them...

Comment: What is the size of your files? If they are larger, 8sec for 20 files is not to bad. You could speed up `read.table`, if you specify the data types using the `colClasses` argument.

Comment: you are right, I don't know why the raster loop has been running for more than 3h now... I will kill it and try the good old read.table...

Comment: `arr<-array(data = NA, dim =   c(360,720,length(files)))`         `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.3 Gb`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (if you have enough memory):

```
#using "raster" package to import data 
rlist <- lapply(files, raster)
s <- do.call(stack, rlist)
rlist <- NULL # to allow freeing of memory
```

It loads all `raster` objects into a big list and then calls `stack` once.

Here's an example of the speed gains: 1.25 sec vs 8 secs for 60 files - but your old code is quadratic in time so the gains are much higher for more files...

```
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
files <- rep(f, 60)

system.time({
 rlist <- lapply(files, raster)
 s <- do.call(stack, rlist)
 rlist <- NULL # to allow freeing of memory
}) # 1.25 secs

system.time({
 s<- raster(files[1])
 for (i in 2:length(files)) {
  r<- raster(files[i])
  s <- stack(s, r)
 }
}) # 8 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried another way to dealing with numerous files.
First I combined the time series raster into one file in the NetCDF format,
Using write.Raster(x,format="CDF",..)
and then just read one file for each year, this time I used brick(netcdffile,varname='') it the reading saves a lot.
However, I need to save each cell's value for all the years according to some predefined format,in which I use write.fwf(x=v,...,append=TRUE)
but it takes a long time for nearly 500,000 points.
Is anyone has the same experiences and help on how to speed up this process?
Here is my code for extracting all the value for each point:

```
weather4Point <- function(startyear,endyear)  
{

  for (year in startyear:endyear)
  {
    #get the combined netCDF file

    tminfile <- paste("tmin","_",year,".nc",sep='')

    b_tmin <- brick(tminfile,varname='tmin')

    pptfile <- paste("ppt","_",year,".nc",sep='')

    b_ppt <- brick(pptfile,varname='ppt')

    tmaxfile <- paste("tmax","_",year,".nc",sep='')

    b_tmax <- brick(tmaxfile,varname='tmax')

    #Get the first year here!!!

    print(paste("processing year :",year,sep=''))

    for(l in 1:length(pl))
    {
      v <- NULL

      #generate file with the name convention with t_n(latitude)w(longitude).txt, 5 digits after point should be work

      filename <- paste("c:/PRISM/MD/N",round(coordinates(pl[l,])[2],5),"W",abs(round(coordinates(pl[l,])[1],5)),".wth",sep='')  

      print(paste("processing file :",filename,sep=''))            

      tmin <- as.numeric(round(extract(b_tmin,coordinates(pl[l,])),digits=1))

      tmax <- as.numeric(round(extract(b_tmax,coordinates(pl[l,])),digits=1))

      ppt <- as.numeric(round(extract(b_ppt,coordinates(pl[l,])),digits=2))

      v <- cbind(tmax,tmin,ppt)

      tablename <- c("tmin","tmax","ppt")

      v <- data.frame(v)   

      colnames(v) <- tablename

      v["default"] <- 0

      v["year"] <- year

      date <- seq(as.Date(paste(year,"/1/1",sep='')),as.Date(paste(year,"/12/31",sep='')),"days")

      month <- as.numeric(substr(date,6,7))

      day   <- as.numeric(substr(date,9,10))

      v["month"] <- month 

      v["day"]  <-  day

      v <- v[c("year","month","day","default","tmin","tmax","ppt")]

      #write into a file with format
      write.fwf(x=v,filename,append=TRUE,na="NA",rownames=FALSE,colnames=FALSE,width=c(6,3,3,5,5,5,6))
    }
  }
}
```